# Can these statements help to take above conclusion?

Tags: logic, problem-solving, decision-theory

There are two statements and one conclusion.
If only first statement helps to check whether following conclusion is correct or not then answer is A.
If only second statement helps to check whether following conclusion is correct or not then answer is B.
If we need both of two statements help to check whether following conclusion is correct or not then answer is C.
If both of two statements does not help to check whether following conclusion is correct or not then answer is D.

statements:
1. Most of boys are clever.
2. John is a boy.

conclusion: John is clever.

This is IQ paper question and it has mentioned C as the answer for this.Is that really correct?Can you help me to get some idea about this?

Comment: The answer is D. "Most of" does not mean "all", therefore none of the statements can help you.

Answer (score 1):

No.   Both statements together do *not* determine whether or not John is clever.

John is a boy and *most* boys are clever, so it is said, but John *may or may not* be among those most boys.

Comment: thank you @Graham Kemp